# Google Cloud Setup - Projects & APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We're looking for best practices on how to setup Projects, APIs, and keys based on our development environment & APIs that we use. In short:

1. We use Google APIs for maps, latitude / longitude, routing, visualizations and a few others.
2. We have 4 development environments from Test > Demo > UAT > Production

Should we setup different projects for each environment with API keys, or setup one project with different keys for each environment? Is there a Google Test environment that we can use for our Test environments so we don't get charged for test scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate project for each functional team; it lets you manage better the permissions for each team, and also it will provide a way to control the cost for each environment. In the document [Best practices](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations) you will find many concepts and recommendation for enterprises.

About the test environments without costs, the answer is no all project on Google Cloud have to be associated to a Billing Account. However, you can take advantage of the [Always Free Usage Limits](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits) for Google Cloud solutions. The same should be applied for  there [MAPS, ROUTES, AND PLACES](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?__utma=102347093.93964716.1536948754.1540342103.1540342103.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1540342103&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1540342103.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=157860154&_ga=2.85178833.991594137.1540249265-93964716.1536948754)

Finally, you can use [Budget Alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) in order to be alerted when your projects reach out the limit you define, it will help you to control costs.